# ODBC DERBY DRIVER for PHP

Tags: php, odbc, derby

I installed easysoft odbc derby driver in windows 7 and try to connect to derby database
after I configure on ODBC Data Source Administrator DSN and connection succeed.

then i tried on php script

```
 //commz is the DSN name ind ODBC data source admin 
$connection = odbc_connect("commz",$user, $password);

if ($result = odbc_exec($connection, "SELECT * FROM ADDRESSBOOK"))
    print "Command executed successfully<BR><BR>";
else
    print "Error while executing command<BR><BR>";

  // Print results
  while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
    print odbc_result($result, 1) . "   " . odbc_result($result, 2) . "   " . odbc_result($result, 3) . "   " . odbc_result($result, 4) . "   " . odbc_result($result, 5) . "<BR>";

  odbc_close($connection);
  print "<BR>Connection closed.";
```

after i run this script this msg appear

Connected to datasource

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Easysoft][ODBC-Derby
>   Driver][DRDA]General error: unexpected command (dss not returned), SQL
>   state HY000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line
>   36 Error while executing command
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 45

Connection closed.

any advise regarding to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do, is send a driver log of the operation to support@easysoft.com and we will take a look at whats going on. I will post whatever we find back here.

To get the log, add to your DSN in odbc.ini file:

```
Logging = Yes
LogFile = /tmp/drb.log
```

Comment: Just to finish this off, we (Easysoft) found it was a driver problem caused by the database name being > 18 char long. Fixed now.