# How do I connect to Derby from VB6?

Tags: vb6, odbc, derby

I am trying to setup a temporary unit test database that has DB2 style syntax. I know Derby fills this role quite nicely on our Java applications.

I have done much searching, and I have seen that you can use the JDBC DB2 driver to connect to Derby - which is cool, except it doesn't seem as true for the ODBC DB2 (or OLEDB) driver allowing a connection to Derby.

I also saw that Cloudscape had a version but following the download instructions, there is a redirect page that states:

[image: redirect page]

There is no replacement for the old Cloudscape ODBC driver in IBM's world. Does anyone know of another source where I can get it? Or another way of connecting to Derby from VB6 (or of creating an ADODB.Connection in VB.net to Derby).

I suppose I would settle for an old version of Derby that the you can connect with (an old) DB2 ODBC driver.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637844/derby-database-odbc-connection (a question in which the moderators have deleted all the useful answers, including mine, apparently because they mention commercial products, which maybe we're not allowed to reference?) Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955368/odbc-derby-driver-for-php

Comment: @Brian This is not a duplicate of those questions. I saw both of those posts before posting. The first one had an accepted answer with an alternate way of migrating his database. Then it mentions the now obsolete cloudscape driver. Neither of which are helpful for anyone who actually needs to connect to Derby via ODBC. The second is not helpful because I don't want to spend hundreds of dollars on a commercial solution.

Comment: OK, if you don't want to buy an ODBC driver, don't. The open source Derby code is a pure JDBC product, as described in both of those questions, and the only way to get ODBC access is to buy a commercial ODBC driver. Sorry you don't find that answer helpful. Perhaps you could write an ODBC driver for Derby and contribute it to the community?

Comment: I have considered creating my own ODBC driver. What irks me is that if this was about 4 years ago, there would be a solution. But IBM is no longer offering that solution. Also, hence my reluctance to spend more money when we should have already had a solution through the DB2 driver we paid for.

Comment: I, too, am sad that IBM's ODBC driver for Derby is no longer available.